# How to create an IDE extension with eclipse 4?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to learn the new application model thingy in Eclipse 4, coming from the previous 3.x world. One thing that is unclear to me is...How to make a Plug-in project like the plain old Plug-in project in 3.x version?

I'm asking because when I try to create a new Eclipse 4 project:

File -> New -> Other -> Eclipse 4 -> Eclipse 4 Application Project and fill the necessary fields, I get a project that if I right click in the .product file and run it, always get a RCP application.

I tried comparing an old 3.x plugin.xml file from a Plug-in 3.x project with a Eclipse 4 plugin.xml project and I can't see any difference that indicates that is going to be a RCP instead of an IDE extension...

I guess I can go with creating a 3.x Plug-in project, but I keep wondering why I can't simply develop IDE extensions using the new Eclipse 4 application model (which I kinda like...)

What I'm missing here? Any ideas? Is it not possible (yet) to develop IDE extensions using Eclipse 4?

Thanks!

Comment: Just for any reader that stumbles here, just got word from Lars Vogel that there is not IDE extension plug-in development available yet, only RCP, at least until Eclipse 4.4...Cross your fingers :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the normal New Plug-in Project to create a plug-in for Eclipse E4. Be sure **not** to select the 'This plug-in will make contributions to the UI' check box as that will introduce Eclipse 3 dependencies.

Use 'New / Eclipse 4 / New Model Fragment' if you want to add an Eclipse 4 model fragment to the plug-in.

Comment: I'm afraid this is incorrect, it will create a RCP but not a plug-in...I've tried that many times and its been confirmed...no Plug-in development is available until 4.4 is released

Comment: I have several projects which use multiple plug-ins for an Eclipse RCP poduct created exactly as I described.

Comment: I guess you do, but I don't want to create a RCP or a simple plug-in, I want to extend the IDE...